# Jenkins Build Error Maven Angular2

Tags: angular, maven, jenkins, build, pom.xml

Getting the error below when I am trying to automate a install and build of an angular 2 application. The application is on GIT and that part is fine. I get as far as the second goal, i can install the nodeModules fine but it fails on the second step which is trying to build the angular application into a dist folder. I basically want it to do the equivalent of ng build --environment=sys in maven.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:exec (ng build) on project consumer-dashboard: Command execution failed. Cannot run program "ng" (in directory "D:\Jenkins\PFS Jobs\consumer-dashboard\workspace\consumer-dashboard\src"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[JENKINS] Archiving D:\Jenkins\PFS Jobs\consumer-dashboard\workspace\consumer-dashboard\pom.xml to consumer-dashboard/consumer-dashboard/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/consumer-dashboard-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
channel stopped
```

Running this in a pom on a build server using Jenkins;

```
<build>
<plugins>
<plugin>
  <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <version>1.4.0</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>npm install</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>exec</goal>
      </goals>
      <phase>generate-sources</phase>
      <configuration>
        <executable>npm</executable>
        <arguments>
          <argument>install</argument>
          <argument>-g angular-cli</argument>
        </arguments>
        <workingDirectory>./src</workingDirectory>
        <target>
          <echo message="npm install" />
        </target>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
    <execution>
      <id>ng build</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>exec</goal>
      </goals>
      <phase>generate-sources</phase>
      <configuration>
        <executable>ng</executable>
        <arguments>
          <argument>build</argument>
          <argument>--environment=sys</argument>
        </arguments>
        <workingDirectory>./src</workingDirectory>
        <target>
          <echo message="ng build" />
        </target>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

Not sure why cannot find ng?

Comment: I would reconsider to use Maven for building an angular app...

Comment: what do you think would work better?

Comment: What about using `ng build...`?

Comment: Thanks khmarbaise, npm build was the way forward, please see below

Comment: I won't use Maven for this kind of apps...Only `ng build...`...

Comment: Im only using maven to build the application in jenkins,nothing more than that

Comment: As I mentioned Maven is a Build Tool for Java apps. But Angular is not Java So I would suggest to only use `ng build` and package the resulting `dist` directory...The question is why do you need Maven?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by doing the following;

```
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <version>1.4.0</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>npm install</id>
              <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
              </goals>
              <phase>generate-sources</phase>
              <configuration>
                <executable>npm</executable>
                <arguments>
                  <argument>install</argument>
                </arguments>
                <workingDirectory>./</workingDirectory>
                <target>
                  <echo message="npm install" />
                </target>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
            <execution>
              <id>ng build</id>
              <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
              </goals>
              <phase>generate-sources</phase>
              <configuration>
                <executable>npm</executable>
                <arguments>
                  <argument>run</argument>
                   <argument>build-sys</argument>
                </arguments>
                <workingDirectory>./</workingDirectory>
                <target>
                  <echo message="ng build" />
                </target>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
```

And in the package.json adding "build-sys";

```
{
  "name": "project-name",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build-sys": "ng build --environment=sys",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  }
```

By doing this i ended up with a dist that contained the correct environment properties.

Thanks to  @khmarbaise for the advice!